# How to close or invalidate connection created by vsphere-automation-sdk-python

Tags: python, vmware, vsphere, vcenter

I am following the samples provided at `https://github.com/vmware/vsphere-automation-sdk-python/tree/master/samples/vsphere/vcenter/vm` to create my python library for doing operations on the VMs. The examples provide the code to get a new connection. I am pasting the sample here.

```
# Connect to vAPI Endpoint on vCenter system
session = get_unverified_session() if args.skipverification else None
client = create_vsphere_client(server=server,
                               username=username,
                               password=password],
                               session=session)
```

What I am missing is once I finish my operation on the VM, how should I close the connection or invalidate the connection. Can I simply say as `client = None` to invalidate the connection ? or is there a documented way to do this ?

Thanks,
Madhav

Comment: Did you manage to find a way to close the session please?. I am also looking for this. Our scripts use the API and after a while they throw the error: 'com.vmware.vapi.endpoint.failedToLoginMaxUserSessionCountReached', default_message='User session count is limited to 550.

Comment: @dealbitte No, I never found this.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

The object returned by the call 'create_vsphere_client' has 2 methods: **exit**() and **del**(). Invoke any of these methods to delete the session. In your case, simply run client.**del**() at the end.

```
def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
   self.__del__()


def __del__(self):
    try:
        self.session_svc.delete()
    except Exception:
        # Catch exceptions when terminating the vSphere session and go ahead
        # close the requests session.
        pass
    if hasattr(self, 'session'):
        self.session.close()
```

Discliamer: I come from Java world, so the terminology above is influenced by this.